# getline(file,line) is skipping lines - C++

Tags: c++, getline, ofstream

I am taking contents from one file and transferring them to another. In particular, I am looking for lines that contain the substring "LIBOR/Swap". However, this is irrelevant and I've commented them out. So, this particular code at the moment really takes every line in one .csv file (file) and transfers them to another .csv file (temp).

The issue is that the transferring skips lines. See attached photos to see the lines that it's skipping in the transfer of data.

[original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB2Pl.jpg)

[new file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv1FM.jpg)

As you can see, with the first **USD LIBOR/Swap** line, it skips the **1 Day** rate. This happens elsewhere throughout the code.

Any reason as to why? Thanks.

```
ifstream file;
ofstream temp;

file.open("YC Rate Levels.csv");
temp.open("Temp.csv");

if (file.is_open())
{
    string line;
    string test = "LIBOR/Swap";

    while (getline(file, line))
    {
          getline(file, line);
        //if(line.find(test) != string::npos)
        //{
            temp << line << endl;
        //}
    }

    temp.close();
    file.close();

} else cout << "File did not open.";

std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n'); 
std::cin.get(); 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling getline(file, line) twice - once inside the while() header and then again inside the body.  Remove the second one.

Comment: That worked. I thought that while statements were conditional? That is, the code just continues while there is a new line. But there is no real "action" of getting a line. Thank you!

Comment: No, the action is performed, a value is returned, and if that value is false then the while loop will terminate.  Otherwise in this case the getline() method would have to know to evaluate but not really run, and all of the methods that it calls as well ...

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.